# Rails caching not working for manual query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activesupport

I'm trying to cache a lot of data (100 000) that i took with an SQL query, but the caching is not working (take about 30sec to write into the cache and the same amount of time to read it) What I'm I doing wrong? my config variable is already set to true

```
    query = "SELECT inscriptions.`id`, banners.`id`, banners.`name`, inscriptions.`registered_at`, 
                inscriptions.`synched_at`, inscriptions.`state`
         FROM inscriptions
         JOIN firm_offices
         ON inscriptions.`firm_office_1_id` = firm_offices.`id`
         JOIN firms
         ON firm_offices.`firm_id` = firms.`id`
         JOIN banners 
         ON firms.`banner_id` = banners.`id`
         GROUP BY inscriptions.`id`"

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
Rails.cache.fetch 'huge-array' do
  data = []
  result.each do |r| 
    data.push({ :id => r[0],
                 :banner_id => r[1],
                 :banner_name => r[2],
                 :registered_at => r[3],
                 :synched_at => r[4],
                 :state => r[5]})
  end
  data
end
@data = Rails.cache.read("huge-array")
```

Comment: It appears that since your query has no conditional around it, it is running every time you run this function. If that's the case, you are negating the usefulness of cache. Have you tried putting a conditional around your query execution?

Comment: What cache store are you using?

Comment: @zoum26, what are you going to do with this data? It seems like the problem isn't with the query or with caching per se, just with instantiating an array of that size. You'll probably want to break the data up into several cacheable chunks (either by doing different SQL queries or just splitting `data` into groups of, say, 10,000), but the best way to do so depends on your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Move it all inside your `fetch` block:

```
@data ||= Rails.cache.fetch 'huge-array' do
  query = "SELECT inscriptions.`id`, banners.`id`, banners.`name`, inscriptions.`registered_at`, inscriptions.`synched_at`, inscriptions.`state`
     FROM inscriptions
     JOIN firm_offices
     ON inscriptions.`firm_office_1_id` = firm_offices.`id`
     JOIN firms
     ON firm_offices.`firm_id` = firms.`id`
     JOIN banners 
     ON firms.`banner_id` = banners.`id`
     GROUP BY inscriptions.`id`"  
  result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
  data = []
  result.each do |r| 
    data.push({ :id => r[0],
             :banner_id => r[1],
             :banner_name => r[2],
             :registered_at => r[3],
             :synched_at => r[4],
             :state => r[5]})
  end
  data
end
```

Notes:

- You don't need to actually move all of it into the block, just the expensive parts (e.g., `execute(query)`).
- Your big SQL query looks like it could translate pretty easily into an AR query. You might want to translate it into an AR query, and then use `to_sql` if that turns out to be more efficient.

Comment: @zoum26, it will take a long time the first time, but should be much shorter on subsequent requests. What is your environment? If you are running in `development`, caching will be turned off by default. You'll need to set `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` in `config/environments/development.rb` (unless you have already done so or are running in production).

Comment: I'm in development, the config variable is set to true... I put rails logger in my code, and even with subsequent requests, when the cache only needs to be read, it is stuck for 30seconds in the reading process. :/

Comment: @zoum26, as Frederick asks above, what cache store are you using?

Comment: I realy don't know, where should I look to see it?

Comment: The default is `memory_store`. You'll want to ensure it is not `null_store`. If you're using memcached or similar, you'll want to ensure your server is running. `config.cache_store` is set in `application.rb` or the `environments` files.

Comment: there's no config.cache_store in my application.rb or development.rb (config environment for development) so I added config.cache_store = :memory_store to development.rb, still no change...

Comment: @zoum26, are you restarting your app (or reloading the console) between `fetch` calls? If you are using `memory_store` then the cache won't persist to a new session. You might try: `config.cache_store = :file_store, Rails.root.join('tmp/cache')`. I just tested my solution (with a slightly different SQL query), and confirmed that it did not redo the query on subsequent requests.

Comment: That's not the problem, the query is not redo since the start, it's just reading it that is super long...

Comment: Oh, really, it's not the query that is the slow part? What is the `size` of `data`?

Comment: The size of data is 119 796

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to run the query and the fetch block each time this function is called. Try something like

```
@data = Rails.cache.read("huge-array")

if @data.empty?
  result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)

  @data = []

  result.each do |r| 
    @data.push({ :id => r[0],
             :banner_id => r[1],
             :banner_name => r[2],
             :registered_at => r[3],
             :synched_at => r[4],
             :state => r[5]})
  end 

  Rails.cache.write("huge-array", @data)
end

return @data
```

This way you only have to do the expensive query + array creation if the data does not already exist in cache.